# Python tool won't stop running-- Not an infinite loop issue

Tags: arcpy

I'm having trouble with a python script.  It is essentially a near duplicate of another script which is running fine-- it is using different files, but apart from that the tools used and the order in which the tools are used is basically the same.

When I go run my duplicate tool, it won't stop running.  It doesn't have any logic in it which would cause it to go into an infinite loop.  It is essentially just a string of tools and outputs.  Does anyone know what it could be about this loop that is keeping it from successfully finishing?

I've tried including print statements, but it seems to freeze so the print statements won't print.

Here is the code (with path named edited):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.geoprocessing.env.overwriteOutput = True   
#Variables
asOldParcelsFC  = r"string"  
asBoundary = r"string"
scParcelsInAS = r"string" 
newNotInOld_preclip = r"string" 
newNotInOld = r"string"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(asOldParcelsFC, "asOldParcels_layer")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(asBoundary, "AltamonteBoundary")
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(scParcelsInAS, "scParcels")

arcpy.AddJoin_management("scParcels", "PARCEL", "asOldParcels_layer", "PARCEL", "KEEP_ALL")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("scParcels", "NEW_SELECTION", "asOldParcels.PARCEL IS NOT NULL")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("scParcels", "SWITCH_SELECTION")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("scParcels", newNotInOld_preclip)
arcpy.Clip_analysis(newNotInOld_preclip, "AltamonteBoundary", newNotInOld)

arcpy.Delete_management(newNotInOld_preclip)
arcpy.Delete_management("AltamonteBoundary")
arcpy.Delete_management("asOldParcels_layer")
arcpy.Delete_management("scParcels")
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, can you please post your code?

Comment: Copy of script added.

Comment: How many features are in your scParcels featureclass? Also, what does your geoprocessing results window look like while this script is running - i.e. what geoprocessing tool is it hanging on?

Comment: 48,147 parcels in scParcels, and it seems to be getting hung up on the first select by attribute.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "using different files"?  What if anything is different between original and new files?

Comment: They use the same files. Ideally, I want them to be the same script-- I just started working with this stage in a separate file to better isolate the problem.  We get an updated parcel layer each month and we want to identify the difference between the old and new layers.  The first script joins the new to the old, selects the old parcels with Null for parcel numbers and exports them to a new FC.  This one is supposed to do exact same thing except by joining the old to the new and selecting the new parcels with Null values.

Comment: When working with large tables and performing joins I would recommend creating an attribute index for both tables, http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000005z000000, this should help the overall process speed wise.

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed the problem.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with large tables and performing joins I would recommend creating an attribute index for both tables, [Add Attribute Index](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/add-attribute-index.htm), this should help the overall process speed wise.